# How to use jQuery Credit Card Validator

Tags: jquery, node.js, coffeescript, validation

I'm looking to validate a credit card number using jQuery Credit Card Validator: http://jquerycreditcardvalidator.com/

For the past couple hours I've tried to familiarize myself with javascript, coffeescript, and jquery so I can figure out how to use it.

These are the steps i've taken to get it to work:

I downloaded coffeescript and node.js as well as jquery.

I compiled the .coffee file I downloaded from the credit card validator site above, which from what I understand turns it into plain Javascript.

Then I downloaded Sublime Text 2 and opened the new .js file and added script tags to the beginning and end.

Finally I saved it as a .html and tried to run it in chrome where nothing happens.

Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious or don't understand the concept, I believe what I'm trying to do is display the form at the top of the Credit Card Validator website above when I drag and drop the .html file into chrome, and from there I can validate my own credit card numbers.

So I'd imagine the "How to Use it section" on the website above is what I need to incorporate, but I have no clue how.

If someone could just point me in the right direction, you'd spare me hours of mindless tutorial surfing. Thanks

Edit: I used `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and got rid of the jquery error, but now just a bunch of text appears and the syntax error mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Since you're in chrome, right-click and hit 'inspect element' -- you'll be able to see in the console if there are any errors. You'll probably need to reload the page with the console open.

Comment: It says jquery is not defined.

Comment: Right - so have you included jQuery? And included jQuery BEFORE your other scripts?

Comment: I have a src= "the .js file that came from the website" at the beginning of the script I downloaded and compiled.

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>` **before** you load any libraries/scripts that depend on it

Comment: now i'm getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: in addition to jquery not defined

Comment: Have you worked it out? I’m the developer of jCCV and will be glad to help if you’re still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha512-UdIMMlVx0HEynClOIFSyOrPggomfhBKJE28LKl8yR3ghkgugPnG6iLfRfHwushZl1MOPSY6TsuBDGPK2X4zYKg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

function ValidateCreditCardNumber() 
        {
            var ccNum = document.getElementById("creditcard").value;
            var visaRegEx = /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/;
            var mastercardRegEx = /^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{14})$/;
            var amexpRegEx = /^(?:3[47][0-9]{13})$/;
            var discovRegEx = /^(?:6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12})$/;
            var isValid = false;

            if (visaRegEx.test(ccNum)) 
            {
                isValid = true;
            } else if(mastercardRegEx.test(ccNum)) 
            {
                isValid = true;
            } else if(amexpRegEx.test(ccNum)) 
            {
                isValid = true;
            } else if(discovRegEx.test(ccNum)) 
            {
                isValid = true;
            }

            if(isValid) 
            {
                alert("Thank You!");
            } else 
            {
                alert("Please provide a valid Visa number!");
            }
        }
```